# Why "hundreds of <noun>s" instead of "hundreds of <noun>"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

In the expression `hundreds of <noun>(s)`, I would think that *hundreds* is what's being modified because *of* is usually right-branching:

> hundreds`<-{of <noun>(s)}`

(This is in contrast to `X hundred <noun>s`, in which *X hundred* is clearly the modifier, and hence the plural.)

If so, I can't see any reason (apart from overwhelming usage, of course!) why `<noun>` must be plural. To me, the idea expressed seems to be a multiplication of some sort:

> X00 * `abstract instance of <noun>`

(This would then be similar to the formal "There are two kinds of person.")

Is the singular archaic, and did we somewhere along the way begin thinking more along the lines of `{hundreds of}-><noun>s` than `hundreds<-{of <noun>}`, or am I completely off?

Evidence from Google Books:

> <strike>I have asked many **hundreds of person** of all classes respecting their own places of residence. (1843)</strike>
>
> <strike>... there was every reason to suppose that an epidemic would be certain to lay claim to **hundreds of victim**. (1869)</strike>
>
> The officers of Police could point to **hundreds of person** who lived solely by picking pockets and other selonious acts ... ([1792](http://books.google.com/books?id=6iwIAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA44&dq=%22hundreds+of+person%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=finlU_DDJ4nboASRpYDYAg&ved=0CFMQ6AEwCDgK#v=onepage&q=%22hundreds%20of%20person%22&f=false))
>
> I have traveled **hundreds of mile** by rail, buggy, lumber wagon, and on foot. ([1889](http://books.google.com/books?id=2vfNAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA58&dq=%22hundreds+of+mile%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7ivlU_PaAob_oQSY-4GQCw&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22hundreds%20of%20mile%22&f=false))
>
> For **hundreds of year** it was the coronation site and burial ground of Polish monarchs, saints, and national heroes. ([2010](http://books.google.com/books?id=cVE0SDn14nUC&pg=PA160&dq=%22for+hundreds+of+year%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wSvlU_j9BM_eoATRn4CYDA&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22for%20hundreds%20of%20year%22&f=false))

Comment: You seem to be very good at finding typos in the Google Books corpus. But this seems to have always been incorrect. See [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hundreds+of+year%2Chundreds+of+person%2Chundreds+of+persons%2Chundreds+of+victim%2Chundreds+of+victims&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chundreds%20of%20year%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chundreds%20of%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chundreds%20of%20persons%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chundreds%20of%20victims%3B%2Cc0). It's possible that *"year"* and *"mile"* are exceptions in some dialects.

Comment: Look closely at your quote for *"hundreds of victim"*. It is really *"hundreds of victim●"*, and I think the blot was probably originally an *"s"*. Your *"hundreds of person"* is [definitely a typo](http://books.google.com/books?id=GUI9AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=%22I+have+asked+many+hundreds+of+persons%22&source=bl&ots=aNcTXr6xS3&sig=ZSiJhEG3t7Z3uxLh-OKEzPLfyAQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-SjlU9fzDea-sQTmlIGgDg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22I%20have%20asked%20many%20hundreds%20of%20persons%22&f=false).

Comment: On the other hand, I do find a remarkable number (although still a small minority) of non-apocryphal instances of *"hundreds of mile"* and *"hundreds of year",* which I would interpret as meaning that these were grammatical in some English dialect (note that *mile* and *year* are both units).

Comment: @PeterShor You are right. My bad for not looking more closely at the print. I've swapped out those quotes for others and added links. I've also included your _mile_ example. Nice find!

Comment: _hundreds of person_ sounds wrong to me, it would normally be _hundreds of people_.

Comment: @PeterShor Hmm - odd, I was going to say that I'm happy to say _It's about two or three mile away_ but the more I say it the more it sounds wrong but it still feels like I have used it. I also think I have said (at some point) _That was five year ago_. _hundreds of year/mile_ does not seem familiar though.

Answer (score 1):

Phrases of the form ***collective noun** of* form the same grammatical role as a specific number. So the parallel is:

- *500* nouns
- *hundreds of* nouns
- *bunches of* nouns

The word before *of* is not being modified, the collective or number quantifies the noun.

Comment: I agree this is how we seem to now think about expressions of this type. But that's why I think the question is interesting. Elsewhere, _of_ strongly marks that the preceeding word is being modified: _subsets of X_, _multiples of 5_, _two of us_, _four of a kind_

Comment: _two of us_ modifies _us_ -- it tells how many there are in _us_. _subsets of X_ could be viewed either way: the subsets are only composed from X, or X is being broken into subsets.

Comment: The simple fact is that the preposition _of_ is used in many different ways. I looked in some dictionary definitions, and none of them seemed to encompass this common use. I was quite surprised.